# How to package styles with a component hosted on NPM?

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6

I have a header and footer react component saved to the NPM repository that i would like to include on various applications. I can include a React component by requiring it from my "parent" application. This will get the React object required to load the component if i have a js document with

```
var HeaderComponent = require('../../node_modules/header-component/dist');
ReactDOM.render(<HeaderComponent />, document.getElementById('header-hook'));
```

But also within that `dist` directory, I there's a `styles` folder with all the required styles for the header. What is the way to package a node module so that it includes accessible styles?

Comment: This should help you if you use webpack: https://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html